# How to use Mixin LESS in external style sheets

Tags: css, less, less-mixins

I have a question about the use of less mixin in different style sheets.

I have 2 sheets of initial styles: reset.less and styleguide.less

I wonder how can I define a mixin in styleguide.less title.

And the reset just use it.

Example:

```
**styleguide.less**

    .title() {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }


**reset.less**

    .h1 {
      .title();
    }
```

Comment: Using [import](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-directives-feature).

Comment: import it the file with the mixin and use it like normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to import the file that has that mixin into reset.less.

If you want to start using shared mixins, then you will most likely want to create a mixins file that you import where you need to.

I precede all imported files with an underscore like `_mixins.less`.

Then import this file into reset.less:

`@import: path/to/_mixins.less;`